# How to prove that she wore the same pair of jewels on $15$ different days

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A girl has $20$ different jewels, she wears $5$ each day.
Prove that in $267$ consecutive days, she wore the same pair of jewels on $15$ different days.

How could I approach this? maybe by using the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Yes, use the pigeonhole principle. Find an optimal strategy for here to minimize the same pair of jewels she wears and then show that even if done optimally the minimum is 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you can use the pigeonhole principle.

Hints:

- How many pairs of jewels are there in total?
- How many pairs of jewels does she wear each day?
- How many pairs of jewels does she wear in $267$ days?
- Averaged across the total number of pairs, on how many days does she wear each pair of jewels in the $267$ days?
- Can that average be achieved if each pair is worn for $14$ days or fewer?

Comment: I got that the average is just a little above 14 days, which means 15.

Comment: Is there an elegant way tho?

Comment: @vpam I think that is about as elegant as it gets